# minimize a product of complex number

Tags: calculus, optimization, complex-numbers

I would like to ask the help from you.
I have the following minimization problem.

Given 2 complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$ and another complex number denote $\omega = \exp(i*\phi)$ ($|\omega|$ = 1), $i$ is the imagine unit, $\phi \in [-\pi, \pi]$. I would like to minimize the squared absolute of $z_1\omega z_2$ given its phase is equal to $\alpha$. Mathematical speaking, we have

$\mathop {\min }\limits_{\phi \in [-\pi, \pi]}$   $|z_1\omega z_2|^2$

s.b.t.   arg($z_1\omega z_2$) = \alpha

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't we have $|z_1 e^{i \phi} z_2|^2 = |z_1|^2 |z_2|^2$ for any $\phi$?

Comment: I think there are some values of $\phi$ should provide a smaller of $|z_1|^2 |z_2|^2$ but I do not know how to find it :(

Comment: Aren't $z_1$ and $z_2$ fixed quantities in your optimization problem? How can changing $\phi$ cause $z_1$ and $z_2$ to change?

Comment: yes, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are fixed, pls see the below thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574805/euclidean-norm-minimization-using-rotations-i-e-min-limits-mathbf-phi-lve?rq=1     It is more or less the same if we scale down to the scalar value instead of vector but my problem has a constraint on phase and that one is no constraint